# SQL extract month from date column and reuse in JOIN command

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

I have an SQL query (Microsoft SQL server) in which I am extracting a month from a date column. I would like to reuse this extracted month in a join command to use it as a criterion to join the result with one more column from another table.

The background is that in the database calendar time is used, but that I need the result in fiscal time. There is one table marrying up calendar time and fiscal time.

When extracting the month from a table I query, I would like to join it to the calendar month part of the marry-up-table, which contains fiscal year and calendar year dates. This table is named MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView and contains both the columns CalendarMemberKeyMonth and FiscalMemberKeyPeriod.

This way, in the end I could add a column with the fiscal month to the result and filter by this instead of the calendar month.

Query that works, but returns NULL for the fields from the calendar - fiscal table:

```
SELECT 
MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.Discipline,
MONTH(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay) AS Month,
SUM(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentMaterialWork) As Materials,
SUM(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentWork) AS Work,
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[CalendarMemberKeyMonth],
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[FiscalMemberKeyPeriod]

FROM MSP_EpmResource_UserView 
     INNER JOIN ((MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
              INNER JOIN MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
          ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID) 

                  INNER JOIN MSP_EpmAssignment ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.ProjectUID 
          AND MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.TaskUID) 

     ON MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID 
     INNER JOIN MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView 
     ON MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID = MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentUID 
     LEFT JOIN MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView
     ON MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.[TimeByDay] = MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.CalendarMemberKeyMonth

WHERE (MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') 
GROUP BY
MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.Discipline, 
MONTH(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay),
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[CalendarMemberKeyMonth],
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[FiscalMemberKeyPeriod]
```

This doesn't work, as the second to last line of the JOIN does not contain the *Month command* I have in the SELECT statement. However, when I add this, the query just runs for minutes (so I cancelled it). This was the following:

```
SELECT 
MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.Discipline,
MONTH(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay) AS Month,
SUM(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentMaterialWork) As Materials,
SUM(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentWork) AS Work,
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[CalendarMemberKeyMonth],
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[FiscalMemberKeyPeriod]

FROM MSP_EpmResource_UserView 
     INNER JOIN ((MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
              INNER JOIN MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
          ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID) 

                  INNER JOIN MSP_EpmAssignment ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.ProjectUID 
          AND MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.TaskUID) 

     ON MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID 
     INNER JOIN MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView 
     ON MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID = MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentUID 
     LEFT JOIN MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView
     ON MONTH(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay) = MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.CalendarMemberKeyMonth

WHERE (MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') 
GROUP BY
MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.Discipline, 
MONTH(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay),
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[CalendarMemberKeyMonth],
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[FiscalMemberKeyPeriod]
```

I have tried implementing a CTE, but haven't succeeded with that, as I keep getting errors that the multi-part identifier could not be bound.

```
WITH CTE(Ass)
AS
--Define CTE query.
(
SELECT MONTH(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay) AS Ass
FROM MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView
)

--Define outer query.
SELECT 
MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.Discipline,
MONTH(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay) As Month,
SUM(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentMaterialWork) As Materials,
SUM(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentWork) AS Work,
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[CalendarMemberKeyMonth],
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[FiscalMemberKeyPeriod],
CTE.Ass

FROM MSP_EpmResource_UserView 
     INNER JOIN ((MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
              INNER JOIN MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
          ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID) 

                  INNER JOIN MSP_EpmAssignment ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.ProjectUID 
          AND MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.TaskUID) 

     ON MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID 
     INNER JOIN MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView 
     ON MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID = MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentUID 
     FULL OUTER JOIN MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView
     ON CTE.Ass = MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.CalendarMemberKeyMonth

WHERE (MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') 
GROUP BY
MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceName,
MSP_EpmResource_UserView.Discipline, 
MONTH(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.TimeByDay),
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[CalendarMemberKeyMonth],
MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.[FiscalMemberKeyPeriod]
```

Is a CTE needed?

Comment: The syntax is clearly SQL Server so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: Can you show the query that "runs for minutes" where you include MONTH in the join because that sounds like the right solution

Comment: What is the name of table that marries up calendar time and fiscal time?

Comment: @PaulHunt : I've added that query to the question (the second one).

Comment: @DanBracuk : I've added that, thanks for asking. It's MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.

Comment: The "multipart identifier could not be bound" error is aggravating in large queries. Make it easier on yourself and use table aliases. Go up the levels of the subqueries from the lowest and validate their results. Reading through your query, I don't see `MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID` as a table source in your _first_ level subquery; could that be your problem?

Comment: @S.Rojak: Thanks for your comment! Hmmm... I don't think `MSP_EpmAssignment. Assignment UID` is causing the problem, as the table is mentioned in the third INNER JOIN. Also I can select that item and make it show in the query result, so I think I the query can access this column. I hope I understood correctly what you were saying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer to my question :)

Nevertheless, Thank you to all of you!

Adding one line, joining on the year as well, solved the issue.
This was probably not solvable, not having the information that other time levels exist as well - I apologise for that, but I hadn't thought that this might be the issue.

So in case anyone is trying to do the same (using MS Project Server), adding the following helps:

```
AND YEAR(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.[TimeByDay]) = MSP_TimeByDay_OlapView.CalendarMemberKeyYear
```

The query now is really slow, but it does work.